# Does not appear right aligned when printing Tabulator 5.1

Tags: javascript, printing, alignment, tabulator, horizontal-alignment

I am using Tabulator version 5.1 and trying to print a table using print function. Alignment of numbers which is set to right does not appear right aligned when printing. When printing all the cells are aligned to left. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Can you attach a code sample?

Comment: Hi Hele, Thanks for your reply....here is working copy on fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/zenderp/4Lj9teh2/14/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and has been fixed in todays 5.1.4 release.

Checkout the [Release Notes](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/release#bugfix) for full details

Comment: Hi Oli,

Thank you for your quick consideration and fixed. So kind of you Oli.......Thank you so much for your fixed. Tabulator is in action in an ERP very soon.....I will contact you very soon....Thank you.